# Javascript set frame width and height

Tags: javascript, frame

I must place afiliate script with iframe, i have this code:

```
Eturas.frame({ width: '100%' });
```

I want set also height: I try this :

```
Eturas.frame({ width: '100%', height: '1000px',  });
```

But this code does not work - where can be a problem?

All code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _et = _et || [];
_et.push(['project', 'daigera-egzotic']);
_et.push(['type', 'hermes']);
_et.push(['url', 'trips/index/type:exotic']);
(function() {
document.write('<' + 'script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.eturas.lt/js/v9/eturas.js"><' + '/script>');
}) ();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Eturas.frame({ style: 'width: 100%; height: 100px;' });
</script>
```

Comment: What error this throws?

Comment: And what's `Eturas.frame()`? I don't recognise the interface. Is that a CSS map it's accepting?

Comment: in which way does your code not work? have you tried to remove the trailing comma inside your argument object?

Comment: In thi sence that `height: 100px ` is not placing in iframe, only `width 100%`

Comment: @sla55er not error, but not set height in iframe and cant't nothing see of iframe because it't 1px height

Comment: Well it's there in the minimised script for height too: `if(sets.width)eFrame.width=sets.width;else eFrame.width='100%';if(sets.height)eFrame.height=sets.height;else eFrame.height=200;`

Comment: "because it't 1px height" - hang on, is the property actually not being set, i.e. you can see it's missing in your browser debugger, or is it just being rendered 1px tall anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would make `$('#idFrame').css('height','100px');` for example with jquery or 
`$("#idFrame").css({"width":"100%","height":"100px"});`